# Maintaining information about people

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I would like advice if this is a good implementation of an application for maintaining information about people (first name, last name, and age).

The index.html contains an empty div and 2 templates (1 for listing people and the other for entering/editing a user):

```
<div id="app">
</div>

<script type="text/template" id="listTemplate">
<!-- Iterates over people and makes a table. -->
</script>

<script type="text/template" id="editTemplate">
<!-- Displays a form which if for existing user will fill the values. -->
</script>
```

In my starting point JS file I put into a namespace 'people.global' a bunch of things that I use throughout the application:

```
$(function() {

    people.global = {
        people: new people.collections.PeopleCollection()
    };

    people.global = $.extend(people.global, {
        listView: new people.views.ListView(),
        editView: new people.views.EditView(),
        router: new people.Router()
    });

    people.global.people.fetch();

    Backbone.history.start();

});
```

The router demonstrates the basic idea which is depending on the screen that should be shown it takes the View's el and draws it in the #app element:

```
var people = people || {};

people.Router = Backbone.Router.extend({

    $app: $('#app'),

    routes: {
        '': 'list',
        'edit': 'edit',
        'edit/:id': 'edit',
        'delete/:id': 'delete'
    },

    list: function() {
        this.$app.html(people.global.listView.render().el);
    },

    edit: function(id) {
        people.global.editView.setId(id);
        this.$app.html(people.global.editView.render().el);
    },

    delete: function(id) {
        var person = people.global.people.get(id);
        person.destroy();
        this.navigate('', {trigger: true, replace: true});
    }

});
```

Below is the view for editing/adding a person:

```
var people = people || {};
people.views = people.views || {};

people.views.EditView = Backbone.View.extend({

    template: _.template($('#editTemplate').html()),

    setId: function(id) {
        this.id = id;
    },

    edit: function() {
        var person;

        if (this.$("#id").val() !== '') {
            person = people.global.people.get(this.id);
            person.set({
                'first': this.$("#first").val(),
                'last': this.$("#last").val(),
                'age': this.$("#age").val()
            });

            person.save();
        } else {
            people.global.people.create({
                first: this.$('#first').val(),
                last: this.$('#last').val(),
                age: this.$('#age').val()
            });         
        }

                people.global.router.navigate('', {trigger: true, replace: true});
    },

    render: function() {
        var person,
            that = this;

        if (this.id) {
            person = people.global.people.get(this.id); 
            this.$el.html(this.template(person.toJSON()));
        } else {
            this.$el.html(this.template({}));
        }

        this.$('button').click(function() {
            that.edit();
        });

        return this;
    }

});
```

Is this a good design choice?

Is there something that can be done better?

Answer (score 1):

All in all, this looks okay to me, proper naming, nothing bizarre, ( no commenting ).

The only thing that bothers me is that you call `.setId(id);` on the `editView`.

`editView` should have a data model with 1 person, and the `.setId()` should be called on that data model ( perhaps your function `setId()` does exactly that ? )

(Deleted race conditions, it not relevant)

Comment: I don't know if this is good. As you can see in EditView edit() method checks for this.id and takes appropriate action.

Comment: I removed my race condition remark, I still feel it's odd that the view get's the data itself instead of getting the data from the controller, or keeping a reference to `this.person` which could be set in `setId`